# Import Angular Component from Github Repository - Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, github, npm, angular-components, angular-module

I want to import an Angular Component from one Project/Module on GitHub into another Project/Module. Here is a link to the test module: https://github.com/tilo-ai/test-mod with a test component. I created another Angular Project locally and ran

```
npm install --save https://github.com/tilo-ai/test-mod
```

The test-mod was added to the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "test-mod": "git+https://github.com/tilo-ai/test-mod.git",
},
```

I tried to import the TestCompComponent in my app.module.ts with

```
import { TestCompComponent } from 'test-mod';
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot find module 'test-mod' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Does anybody know what is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution if the error is appearing in your editor.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1915

Comment: I think the error occurs because I am still missing general things. For example, I don't have a Types file. I just created an Angular project with ng new my-project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the module not the component. I did the same, but after that, I stopped to another error: `cannot find properties of undefined(reading 'emod')`.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30075994)